# Reply Form doesn't show when Reply button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, blogger

I use my browser's debugger and it found 2 errors: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addComment' of null" and "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null".

I don't know which parts of the theme I'm using cause these errors so I attach my test blog link and my theme code for you to look at. Thank you in advance for any kind of help.

**Theme code:** https://controlc.com/e82f15be

**Test blog:** https://kiotestbloghhe.blogspot.com/2021/08/123.html

Comment: Testing a comment seems to work now, I am being redirected to Google in order to verify my identity. I guess this is how it should work?

Comment: @anatolhiman My mistake. I configured only users with a Google account could comment. I have changed it so that you can comment as anonymous. And yes it's fine to add new comments but replying to previous comments doesn't work.

Comment: There are 10 different console errors. You have to go through them one by one and fix before all the scripts will load correctly. Only then you'll see if this really works or not. Some JS if not most JS is blocked by the errors. You try to load two different versions of jQuery, but one is blocked because it's loade over http (change to https). Go through the code and remove unnecessary stuff like google ads, fix http to https and it will be easier to find the real error. Also: blogspot isn't an up to date and good system, you could consider using a better platform.